# PDFKIT , Swift How to remove pdf (PDFDocument) from uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pdfkit, nsdocumentdirectory

i have this code for download PDF file :

```
var documents = [PDFDocument]()

  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {
            //All stuff here

            print("Download PDF");
            let url=NSURL(string: urlString);
            let urlData=NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL);

            if((urlData) != nil)
            {
                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

                let fileName = urlString as NSString;

                let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";

                let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: filePath)

                if(fileExists){

                    // File is already downloaded
                    print("PDF Already Downloaded");
                }
                else{

                    //download
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                        print(filePath)
                        urlData?.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true);
                        print("PDF Saved");

                        self.refreshData()
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

Now  I want to remove this file from uitableview in table and in    documentdirecotry how to use index path row and how to find file name for removing

i know i will remove the file here but i don't know how to exactly remove the PDF in documentDirectory and Table

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)

    }
```

}

here is my table view cell

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BookshelfCell

        let document = documents[indexPath.row]
        if let documentAttributes = document.documentAttributes {
            if let title = documentAttributes["Title"] as? String {
                cell.title = title
            }
            if let author = documentAttributes["Author"] as? String {
                cell.author = author
            }
```

here is my refresh data part

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    documents = contents.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: $0) }
```

Comment: People will be able to help you better if you explain your table view setup a bit better.

Comment: what your sugestion i great update the code @Matthew Seaman ?

Comment: I see you added a few more things. Should be more helpful.

Comment: can find one solution for remove exactly from NSDirectory @MatthewSeaman ?

Comment: See @theMikeSwan 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to complete three steps to properly delete the document and update your table view:

1. Use `FileManager`'s `removeItem(at: URL)` or `removeItem(atPath: String)` to delete the file from disk. (note that both of these methods throw so you need to use a do-catch block along with `try` and only proceed if the method didn't throw an error.) **Update**: If you look at the [documentation for PDFDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument) you will find that in addition to the `documentAttributes` that you are already using there is another optional property, `documentURL` that should give you exactly what you need to remove it.
2. Remove the document from `documents` (you could just refresh the whole array using your existing code but removing a single item is faster). `documents.remove(at: indexPath.row)`
3. Finally, you need to tell the table view to remove the row in question (you could of course just reload the whole table view but removing the single cell is cleaner) `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with .fade)`

In case you are unfamiliar with do-catch blocks here is a bit of code from Apple's book on Swift (see below for link) simplified a bit:

```
do {
    try makeASandwich()
    eatASandwich() // This only gets called if the line above worked
} catch {
    dealWithTheError() // This only gets called if makeASandwich() throws an error
}
```

## Side Note

Apple has a fantastic guide on the [Swift Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) if you haven't done so yet I suggest reading, at least, *The Basics*. This will give you a base understanding of the language. If you are also new to programming I would suggest going through Apple's Learn to Code series that is *free* on iPads in the Swift Playgrounds app. The series will guide you through all the basics of programming giving you the tools to search through the documentation that Apple provides and find answers to your questions.

We all started at the beginning at some point, and we all had to crawl before we could walk and well before we could run.

Comment: thanks @theMikeSwan
can you wrote a exactly code please because i am new in swift

Comment: i need to find url for remove from table view in this  part removeItem(at: URL) can you helping me

Comment: thanks just i great add this part ,   documents.remove(at: indexPath.row)
 ,refreshData()   but for  removeItem(at: URL how can i call the FileManager and how can i find a fid a path name or url address for add in if is possible to wrote a code for this its so complicated for me @theMikeSwan

Comment: is that possible to find path or url  (FileManager) with index path

Comment: You have to get the URL the same way you get the `documentAttributes`. Instead of using `if let documentAttributes = document.documentAttributes` like you do for the attributes use `if let documentURL = document.documentURL`

Comment: is that correct ?
 let document = documents[indexPath.row]
                let documentURL = document.documentURL
                
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: (documentURL?.path)!)

Comment: That should work for step one, you could also use the first method mentioned in step one to delete the document that takes a URL rather than a path.I would recommend that you use `if let` for getting the document url just like you do in your `cellForRowAt` method. Otherwise if the url is ever nil the app will crash. Also, you can use the back tick character ` to delineate code within comments, questions, and answers.